# How to use TimeDsitributed layer for neural network ensmeble (specifically CNN+LSTM)?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

So this is the first of 2 ways that I tried:

```
inputs=Input(shape=(frames, 103*4, 1))

z=TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (5,25), padding='same', activation='relu'), input_shape=(frames, 103*4, 1))(inputs)
z=TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(z)
z=TimeDistributed(ReLU())(z)
z=TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2))(z)
z=TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))(z)

z=TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3,5), padding='same', activation='relu'))(z)
z=TimeDistributed(BatchNormalization())(z)
z=TimeDistributed(ReLU())(z)
z=TimeDistributed(Dropout(0.2))(z)
z=TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))(z)

z=TimeDistributed(Flatten())(z)

z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)
z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)
z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)

z=Flatten()(z)

z=Dense(1000, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

z=Dense(500, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

z=Dense(200, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

outputs=Dense(88, activation='sigmoid')(z)
```

I'm getting this error (although I don't have strides size of 2 anywhere in my code):

```
ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 1 or 3 but was 2
```

I've already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064838/strides-should-be-of-length-1-1-or-3-but-was-2) and it seems that I've implemented the advice given in my code. But what's the problem? I can't get a grasp of it.

Finally I managed to combine CNN and LSTM via FunctionalAPI of Keras:

```
inputs=Input(shape=(frames, 103*4, 1))

z=Conv2D(32, (5,25), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
z=BatchNormalization()(z)
z=ReLU()(z)
z=Dropout(0.2)(z)
z=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2))(z)

z=Conv2D(32, (3,5), padding='same', activation='relu')(z)
z=BatchNormalization()(z)
z=ReLU()(z)
z=Dropout(0.2)(z)
z=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2))(z)

z=TimeDistributed(Flatten())(z)

z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)
z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)
z=LSTM(1000, dropout=0.1, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(z)

z=Flatten()(z)

z=Dense(1000, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

z=Dense(500, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

z=Dense(200, activation='relu')(z)
z=Dropout(0.5)(z)

outputs=Dense(88, activation='sigmoid')(z)


model=Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

It works, but I'm still at a loss if that's the right way. I can see via `model.summary()` that my TimeDstributed wrapper has output shape `(None, 7, 3296)` and all LSTM layers have output shapes `(None, 7, 1000)`. What should I change to give it center frame instead of 7 frames?

Speaking of my dataset, I give 7 frames of amplitudes of frequencies values to predict values in the center frame.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to apply the TimeDistributed layer over the frames dimension which makes our input to be of 2-dimension which is sent to the convolution layer.
If that is the case then you should use Conv1D not Conv2D. Change the kernel size accordingly.
Also change Maxpooling2D to Maxpooling1D accordingly.

For eg.

```
z=TimeDistributed(Conv1D(32, 2, padding='same', activation='relu'))(inputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

@priyach You're right, but as I can see I gave a somewhat poor explanation of my dataset. I have 2d arrays with time on x axis and frequency on y axis (trying to predict notes being played given information about frequencies)

So if I'd fed columns of my 2d array (each representing all frequencies at a given time) into my network, then Conv1D and MaxPooling1D would be the right choice

But instead of columns as inputs I feed each column surrounded by 3 cols to the left of it and 3 cols to the right of it (or using zero-padding then I can't get columns). So my input is essentially 2d and I treat it as images.

I managed to create another network (CNN+DNN+LSTM+DNN) and used a Reshape layer before 1st LSTM layer (instead of TimeDistributed).

Still the question remains (out of curiosity and for future programming). What's wrong with that my usage of the TimeDistributed layer?